# Any recommended alumni tracking system that integrates with Civi?

Tags: civicase

We are a small non-profit school (around 70 students) and we would like to keep some stats on our alumni so we can measure how well are doing at training.

1. Is this something you would use CiviCase for?
2. Do you recommend any other systems out there for this?

Edit:
We specifically want to track several things.

1. Class dropouts
2. Location of where they land a job within area of training
3. How long from graduation to working within field of training
4. They will be working in teams (not necessarily just teams of our alumni) so we want to be able to see team connections across our crm.
5. Stages of advancement within field of training and team successes/accomplishments
6. How long working in said field

Since we are a small tight-knit school, we have continuing relationships with our alumni. So we will likely get a high response rate to annual surveys that can keep the data base updated.

Comment: most of above sounds like straightforward with custom fields and relationships plus Activities. agree with Demerit that Case may be overkill. if you mention your CMS you may get Webform/Caldera/Form Builder specific answers

Comment: CMS is Drupal so Webforms and views are available.

Comment: I would go down that route then as it offers great flexibility.

Comment: Weighing out using Individual contact sub-types vs membership for Student and Alumni. Would there be any major pros and cons of one over the other for this use case scenario?

Comment: I would use membership if there is Start and End dates (eg if folk pay for their status) otherwise why not just use a Tag?

Comment: oh. i would use sub-contact type if you have different custom fields for a Student v an Alumni, eg for an Alumni you may want to know 'year left school', university attended etc etc, which is not data you have for a student

Comment: but note that changing someone from being a Student to an Alumni would then lose any custom student fields you might have. i think we have all fields on 'individuals' and use Tags to separate

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

CiviCase might be overkill. Maybe if you had several steps involved with each alumni outreach and wanted to track those steps separately but count the number of outreaches as a whole, but otherwise just one or two regular activities should do it? Or CiviCampaign with a survey.